# What exactly is an Asset in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-chaincode

According to Hyperledger Fabric website, it states:

> Assets can range from the tangible (real estate and hardware) to the
>   intangible (contracts and intellectual property). Hyperledger Fabric
>   provides the ability to modify assets using chaincode transactions.

If my use case for a HF Blockchain is to store service logs of vessels, then are the **Assets** the vessels in this case?

But what modifications are to be made to the asset when I am not transferring the assets or changing its states? I am only keeping an immutable record of the service performed to the vessels.

Could anyone explain this for my use case? Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your setup.

Your vessels could be assets yes, if you need to store them on the ledger. The logs are also assets and they could link back to vessels via an id which uniquely identifies the vessel.

You could also not store the vessels on the ledger at all. if they are defined and maintained in another system then you could only have the logs as assets, still linking via a VesselId.

If you don't want the logs modified at all then you could some ACL rules which stop any changes once the asset is created.

So yeah, you have multiple options available depending on what you want to do.

In very simple terms, assets are the objects you want to maintain on the ledger.

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on the way you model your Network.

In the use case which you stated, you can have Vessels as assets and Services on these vessels as Transactions. Additionally, you can have a "ServiceLog" Asset which is linked to a Vessel. This may or may not be required and depends on what information you want to log and how you want to process this information later. 
If you just want to log the date and time of the service along with who conducted it, for the purpose of verification, then the blockchain does it for you (You can use the historian to track this information).

But if you want more details in your logs then it is a good idea to have a ServiceLog asset and link it to a Vessel.

Answer (score 0):

The ASSET in this case is indeed the Vessel.  The ServiceLog is no longer needed, as the LEDGER now acts as the ServiceLog, and will record all transactions.
The TRANSACTION in this case is SERVICE, and all its requisite information will be recorded in ordered, dated, format to the Ledger, in immutable form.  In other words, transactions, first need to be setup, and then associated with asset types, after which the transaction "SERVICE" and the associated data elements can be recorded against the specific asset "VESSELid".